# Lighten svg part on hover without knowing original color

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

Ok, so I have made a piechart with angular and svg.
It looks ok, but it is not really responding that well to hover events.

```
<path (click)="pieClick(cat)" class="slice" [attr.fill]="getColor(i)" [attr.d]="getArc()"></path>
```

That is the path that draws a pie slice. it should be noted here that the colors must be fetched from a backend server, so I cannot simply hardcode this into the css.

The css that I have right now looks like this

```
.slice {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slice:hover {
    fill: #333;
}
```

And it works, but preferably I would like to just lighten the color on hover instead of setting it to `#333`.

Can this be done with pure CSS or do I need to somehow map that property to angular code?

Comment: To be honest with you, I am not familiar with those terms. I am using "pure" old css

Comment: How about adding an `opacity` on hover?

Comment: Yeah, using opacity is a smart way of solving it in some cases(and probably my best bet) but what if I have a dark background? then I would need to add either svg or html for this to work. so if at all possible I would like to do this with only css

Comment: Are you using SASS or LESS? If so you could use lighten(). Also you can use CSS function brigthness() or change opacity.

Comment: reading up a little bit, I am not using SASS or LESS. and adding a `filter: brightness(1.5);` does nothing

Comment: I would use hsl colors and change brightness on mouse over.

Comment: @munHunger you will need vendor prefix (ie -webkit-filter:, -moz-filter, etc).

Comment: If you use `rgba(r, g, b, a)` instead of `#rgb` you can use simply modify the alpha channel on hover with a little javascript. Also, if you use a library for charts, there's *most likely* an onHover() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially do it by creating a white div in front, and adding an alpha channel to make it partially transparent.

Try running the snippet below and see if it does what you need.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box:hover::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box black"></div>
<div class="box yellow"></div>
```

Comment: Even if a bit more complicated as I cannot use the `:after` method due to the shape not being square, this actually works quite well with little modifications!

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.5);
-moz-filter: brightness(1.5);
-ms-filter: brightness(1.5);
filter: brightness(1.5);
```

Comment: still no change even with the vendor prefixes. (using chrome)

Comment: You can't apply such filters to SVG content in Chrome I believe. Firefox does support these kind of filters on SVG content though.